# Java GUI getComponent(), panel.remove()

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, chess

I started creating GUI for my Chess school project. And i got seriously stuck, while trying to implement figure moving.

I've got a window LayerPane, which represents main application window. In this LayerPane I've got next chess Pane in which I put a testing Pane.

So its like - window - chessboard - testing

Im trying to make testing pane disappear on click like this.
(Code generated by NetBeans)

```
private void testingPaneMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                           
    Component Fig = evt.getComponent();

    System.out.println(Fig);

    jLayeredPane1.remove(Fig);
    jLayeredPane1.repaint();
}
```

But whenever i click on the testing Pane, nothing happens. The cause is that getComponent() method returns chessboard Pane instead of testing Pane.

Any advice, how to get testing pane?

When I try t delete it directly, it of course works.

```
jLayeredPane1.remove(testingPane);
```

Any help appreciated!

Thanks so much!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Call `revalidate()`, that should do the trick:

```
panel.remove(child);
// tell the panel to re-calculate its internals
panel.revalidate();
// now repaint - doesn't get automatically called
panel.repaint()
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply iluxa. But I already tried, like, everything including revalidate.

The problem is, the evt.getComponent(); won't identify the chessboards child, but the chessboard itself, so the child cannot eb deleted in next step.

Comment: Problem seems to be solver. I added listener to test Pane, rather than to chessabord and it seems to work correctly.